# Cookie works when I use Postman, but does not show in browser

Tags: node.js, express, npm, cookies, pug

I am working on a Nodejs Project and pug template. When I login on postman, Cookie is sent, but when I use Chrome or any other browser, It does not show cookie

```
const signToken = (id) => {
  return jwt.sign({ id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
    expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN,
  })
}

const createSendToken = (user, statusCode, req, res) => {
  const token = signToken(user._id)

  res.cookie('jwt', token, {
    expires: new Date(
      Date.now() + process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES_IN * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    ),
    httpOnly: true,
  })


  res.status(statusCode).json({
    status: 'success',
    token,
    data: {
      user,
    },
  })
}
```

I also am using `cookie-parser` and `cors` from npm

```
app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
  })
)
```

I have tried using cors without any option. Still doesnt work.

When I log req.cookies to the console, I get

```
[Object: null prototype] {}
```

But using postman, I get the jwt token displayed in the console.

Here is my login route. How do I include the credentials

```
export const login = async (email, password) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/users/login',
      data: { email, password },
    })

    if (res.data.status === 'success') {
      showAlert('success', 'Logged in successfully!')
      window.setTimeout(() => {
        location.assign('/')
      }, 1500)
    }
    console.log(res)
  } catch (err) {
    showAlert('error', err.response.data.message)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

httpOnly cookies are set by the server and arent accessible by the browser, only the server. When making your request try adding `withCredentials: true` in an axios (or `credentials: 'include'` for fetch):

```
axios.post('/your-route', {your-body}, {withCredentials: true});
-- or --
fetch('/your-route', {credentials: 'include'}) 
//may need cross-origin or same-origin if CORS Origin is set
```

Check out the mozilla docs on using http cookies for further reference
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies

Comment: I just modified my initial question to include my axios post, how can I do it withcredentials

Comment: `const res = await axios({method: 'POST', url: URL, data: {DATA}, withCredentials: true})`

Answer (score 1):

I had to look for it, the whole day, I found that using http://localhost:3000 instead of http://127.0.0.1:3000 was all I needed for the solution, try this.....

Comment: and yes, withCredentials should be set to true from the client side to send cookies back to the server and there too, we are supposed to add Credentials to true in cors

Comment: Are you aware that you can [edit] your posts? Try, e.g. by improving according to [answer]. Taking the [tour] should have helped you with basics like this.